# Renaming appendix numbers to S1 and S2 instead of A and B

Tags: appendices, elsarticle

I am writing an assignment, and as per the instructions,

> Appendices must follow the naming format “Appendix S1,” Appendix S2,”
> and so on.

I am using the `elsarticle` class. So far, I have tried.

```
\appendix
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}
```

But, it by default starts as `A`. Is there any way the naming format can start from S instead of A?

Comment: Your title agrees with the instructions, but disagrees with your last paragraph.

Comment: While it's ok to upvote answers that you find useful immediately, site instructions strongly suggest waiting for at least a few hours, and ideally a day or more, before "accepting" any particular answer. That way, you don't inadvertently discourage other readers from posting additional, and potentially even better, answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Appendices must follow the naming format “Appendix S1,” Appendix S2,” and so on.

The `elsarticle` document class contains the following, rather ill-conceived instructions regarding appendix sections and their contents:

```
\def\appendixname{Appendix }
\renewcommand\appendix{\par
  \setcounter{section}{0}%
  \setcounter{subsection}{0}%
  \setcounter{equation}{0}
  \gdef\thefigure{\@Alph\c@section.\arabic{figure}}%
  \gdef\thetable{\@Alph\c@section.\arabic{table}}%
  \gdef\thesection{\appendixname~\@Alph\c@section}%
  \@addtoreset{equation}{section}%
  \gdef\theequation{\@Alph\c@section.\arabic{equation}}%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\string\let\string\numberline\string\tmptocnumberline}{}{}
}
```

Notice, in particular, the atrocity `\gdef\thesection{\appendixname~\@Alph\c@section}`, which makes is impossible to cross-reference appendix sections properly via `\autoref` and `\cref`, which are two user-level macros provided by the `hyperref` and `cleveref` packages, respectively.

To achieve your desired formatting and to restore normal cross-referencing capabilities, I suggest you run the following instructions after executing `\appendix`:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{\@ifundefined{#1@cntformat}%
   {\csname the#1\endcsname\space}%    default
   {\csname #1@cntformat\endcsname}}%  enable individual control
\newcommand\section@cntformat{\appendixname\thesection.\space} % section-level
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\thesection}{S\arabic{section}}
\counterwithin{equation}{section}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\counterwithin{table}{section}
```

---

[image]

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
\usepackage{cleveref} % for '\cref' command
\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\noindent
Cross-references to \cref{app:hello,app:world,eq:pyth,fig:here,tab:there}. 


\appendix

\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{\@ifundefined{#1@cntformat}%
   {\csname the#1\endcsname\space}%    default
   {\csname #1@cntformat\endcsname}}%  enable individual control
\newcommand\section@cntformat{\appendixname\thesection.\space} % section-level
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\thesection}{S\arabic{section}}
\counterwithin{equation}{section}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\counterwithin{table}{section}

\section{Hello} \label{app:hello}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:pyth} a^2+b^2=c^2 \end{equation}
\begin{figure}[h] \caption{A figure caption}\label{fig:here} \end{figure}

\section{World} \label{app:world}
\begin{table}[h] \caption{A table caption}\label{tab:there} \end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

I concur with [Mico's analysis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/708552/4427) that the code for `\appendix` in `elsarticle.cls` is dreadful.

However, I don't agree with complicated code in the middle of the document. Also, some changes to Mico's proposal seem necessary, but his ideas are, as usual, very good.

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
\usepackage{cleveref} % for '\cref' command

\makeatletter
\newif\if@els@appendix
\renewcommand\appendix{\par
  \global\@els@appendixtrue
  \setcounter{section}{0}%
  \setcounter{subsection}{0}%
  \setcounter{equation}{0}%
  \counterwithin{figure}{section}%
  \counterwithin{table}{section}%
  \counterwithin{equation}{section}%
  \gdef\thesection{S\arabic{section}}% <--- HERE THE NUMBERING FORMAT
  \addtocontents{toc}{\string\let\string\numberline\string\tmptocnumberline}{}{}
}
\NewCommandCopy{\els@seccntformat}{\@seccntformat}
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{%
  \ifcsname format@#1\endcsname
    \csname format@#1\endcsname
  \else
    \els@seccntformat{#1}%
  \fi
}
\newcommand{\format@section}{%
  \if@els@appendix \appendixname\fi\els@seccntformat{section}%
}
\def\tmptocnumberline#1{%
   \settowidth\appnamewidth{\appendixname S00}%
   \hb@xt@\appnamewidth{\appendixname #1\hfill}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Introduction}

Cross-references to \cref{app:hello,app:world,eq:pyth,fig:here,tab:there}. 

\appendix

\section{Hello} \label{app:hello}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:pyth} a^2+b^2=c^2 \end{equation}
\begin{figure}[htp] \caption{A figure caption}\label{fig:here} \end{figure}

\section{World} \label{app:world}
\begin{table}[htp] \caption{A table caption}\label{tab:there} \end{table}

\end{document}
```

Using a copy of the class defined `\@seccntformat` ensures uniformity in the output. I also change how the table of contents is printed so as to make it similar to `elsarticle`’s.

I didn't “abstract” also the numbering of the appendix, but the place where it's defined is clearly marked.

Advantage of this approach: if the copy editors don't agree with your style, you just remove the added code in the preamble. However, if you happen to use `cleveref`, several changes in the document would be needed.

Note that `cleveref` is by no means necessary for the code to work.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
\appendix
\setcounter{section}{18}%. is R, next will be S
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}
```

Comment: This doesn't quite work: The first appendix section will be labeled `S`, the second appendix section will be labeled `T`, and so on. According to the OP's write-up, though, the appendix sections are supposed to be numbered `S1`, `S2`, etc.